# Weird SSD behavior under TinyCore. I/O errors with Java programs, none with dd

Tags: linux, ssd, java

I'm using pxelinux to deploy an in-ram version of TinyCore (Linux version 4.19.10-tinycore). It's running on a Z270-A motherboard with latest BIOS (as of today). PXE is booted in legacy mode.

I wrote a Java application that deploys SSD images over the network, writing them using RandomAccessFile. I've been experiencing weird behavior when writing, specifically this:

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42319888
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 5289986, async page read
ata1: EH complete
ata1.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x40000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:90:10:c0:85/00:00:02:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 in
         res 41/40:00:10:c0:85/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#18 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 02 85 c0 10 00 00 08 00
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 42319888
Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 5289986, async page read
ata1: EH complete
ata1.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

I've tried disabling NCQ using `libata.force=noncq` but to no avail.

**The weird thing is,** no such errors occur when wiping the device using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M` and then attempting to write data again with my program. It looks like filling the drive with zeros fixes the issue, but this takes a really long time and it's not beneficial for the device's health.

For this specific reason, I implemented the program writing the image in such a way that, before writing the actual data, zeros are written to simulate the above command. Even so, the error still happens.

`smartctl -a /dev/sda` does not show any bad signs. I've seen this happen with multiple devices, such as Silicon Power S55 and Micron 1100. This *only* happens in this setup. It never happened with an installed version of Ubuntu 18.04 (ran from a disk, not from ram).

The ram is not faulty, tested with memtest. All cables are good, running off a Corsair RM1000i.

Here is an output of [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/QhkvBgEv). I cannot seem to find a way to fix this, I'm lost at this point. Also, here is [smartctl](https://pastebin.com/3CsPawbt) output.

EDIT: It does not always happen at the same sector. Sometimes it happens at a sector that worked fine in the past. It looks random.

EDIT2: My program opens `/dev/sda` as a file and executes I/O on it (this is how I write to the disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the messages were indeed false errors. I have changed my Java code, instead of using `FileOutputStream` I now use this handy library: http://www.nicecode.eu/java-streams-for-direct-io/

It provides native I/O access to files using JNA, and I can set the O_DIRECT flag on. I have modified the library, increasing the buffer from BLOCK_SIZE (512 bytes) to 512KB (512*1024). The buffer size has to be a multiple of the block size, which for O_DIRECT must be 512 bytes. This way, speeds are reasonable, comparable to Java's non-native implementation.

There are no errors anymore, all the data is valid (confirmed using `md5sum`), for neither the previously tested Silicon Power SSD or the new Micron one.